# Is it a good practice to add favorites , like/dislikes and views (watched posts) in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `views` (
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  'liked' tinyint(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  'favorited' tinyint(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Is this a good approach for performance and reducing query numbers?
or its better to have 3 separate table?

Comment: It is necessary. If you merge them, how will you count like by concrete user?

Comment: Note: A Table named `views` is not a `view` in seight of mySQL.

Comment: @VasylZhuryk its possible with where liked = 1 and user_id = $id

Comment: @MarkusZeller i know . its just a name

Comment: This is junction table. So it is safe. The only point you must enter data using INSERT .. ODKU only, not single INSERT. Additionally you may think about one field of SET datatype.

Comment: @VasylZhuryk Each records refers on one definite user and one definite post.

Comment: Please define "good" so that we can understand what you aim to achieve.

Comment: @LajosArpad performance, scalability and maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably each distinct `user_id` can "like" or "favorite" each distinct `post_id` just once. That means your `liked` and `favorited` columns have either the value `0` or `1`.

So this setup is tolerable.

But, when a user has already "liked" a post and then "favorites" it, your logic will be more complex than if you had two separate tables. With separate tables all you have to do when a user "likes" a "post" is `INSERT IGNORE` a row. When a user "unlikes" a post all you have to do is `DELETE` the row. It makes for cleaner and sorter code, always good.

You don't need your `TINYINT` columns in this case. The presence of the row in the table is enough to indicate "liked" or "favorited."

You could also throw in a column like this to each table.

```
datestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then, with no extra code in your app, you would have a record of when the user "liked" or "favorited" the post.

You can get this stuff out of the tables something like this.

```
SELECT user.whatever, post.whatever, 
       CASE WHEN like.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'liked' ELSE '' END liked,
       CASE WHEN fav.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'favorited' ELSE '' END favorited
  FROM user
  JOIN post
  LEFT JOIN like
        ON user.user_id = like.user_id AND post.post_id = like.post_id
  LEFT JOIN fav
        ON user.user_id = fav.user_id AND post.post_id = fav.post_id
  WHERE user.user_id = WHATEVER
    AND post.post_id = WHATEVER
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ... `IS NOT NULL` detects the presence of the liked or favorited row.

Comment: You said _When a user "unlikes" a post all you have to do is DELETE the row_ , but it's possible that user _disliked_ the post rather than un-checking the _like_ button(which kinda gives a neutral perspective). This way, we have to keep track of _dislikes_ too or maybe a enum column in _like_ table.

Comment: "Dislikes" are another category of user / post flag. The solution I presented only covers "likes".  As far as I can see the OP didn't mention "dislikes" as a requirement, so I didn't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Most importantly, you lose the information of *who* has upvoted or liked a particular post. That makes it difficult to track "retractions", when someone undoes their like or favorite.

You also cannot know how many upvotes/likes a person makes. Is someone an angel who upvotes everything? Or a curmudgeon?

In addition, maintaining the column requires updating a row. Updates are generally more expensive than addition new rows. This is only an issue during high volume periods, when there might be contention for the same data pages. `insert`s have much less contention.

There are some cases where such an approach might be fine. As a general rule, though, I think that as a general rule, separate tables for likes and upvotes and more appropriate.

Comment: *you lose the information of who has upvoted* ? if so what is `user_id`? the post author is an attriburte in posts table...

Comment: @Akina . . . It would seem strange that a user could like or upvote a post more than once, so I don't consider that a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Why more than once? I think OP uses TINYINT(1) for to use it as BOOLEAN which is absent in MySQL. So post is either liked or not. And maybe the user may change his opinion and drop previous upvote (or remove from favorites)... and then he may re-upvote it back.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two different tables.

One table Likes/dislikes and one table for favorites.

Example:

```
favorites
  |
   -> user_id
   -> post_id

likes:
  |
   -> user_id
   -> post_id
   -> like->boolean
   -> dislike->boolean
```

This way you can always track what is what, and easier to work with. if you do both in one table it'll get way more complex. Why make something hard if it can be easy? The setup is a little more work but eventually you'll be happy that you separated these.